# Azure Active Directory Group Membership Claims not all are being returned

Tags: azure-active-directory

According to this article, [Simple Talk - Azure Active Directory Part 4 Group Claims](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/cloud/security-and-compliance/azure-active-directory-part-4-group-claims/), when I set the "groupMembershipClaims" setting in my application manifest, the group claims, including nested should get returned.

This does not appear to be the case in my situation.  I am only getting back the groups that a user is directly associated with.

Example setup:  Group 1 has member of Group 2 has member of User 1.

When the user logs in the only group claim that gets sent back is for Group 2, when according to the article I should be receiving Group 1 and Group 2.

Is there some setting in Azure AD that needs to be flipped to allow this to happen? The article says it should just happen without any other changes other than in the application manifest.

Comment: Hmm, that is pretty weird. I just tested this and it worked. It should be returning transitive memberships too, i.e. when a user is a member of a group which is a member of another group like you have.